# VS2015: XAML Designer: Error: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002"

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015+SP1, the XAML designer is showing this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.NativeMethods.SafeOpenFile(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.FileMapping..ctor(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataDispenser.OpenFileAsFileMapping(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.Loader.ResolveModule(Assembly containingAssembly, String moduleName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.DefaultUniverse.ResolveModule(Assembly containingAssembly, String moduleName)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.SimpleUniverse.Microsoft.MetadataReader.ITypeUniverse.ResolveModule(Assembly containingAssembly, String moduleName)
...
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

## Update

Went through the Microsoft recommendations for fixing this error, see [Debugging or Disabling Project Code in XAML Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622752.aspx).

Comment: All the time or just when you open a specific project/xaml flle?

Comment: Just tested it with a brand new WPF app, and works fine. So it must be something related to the project I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because I was using [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), and the project I was working in was missing some assemblies that the entry project required.

When I added the required assemblies, the error disappeared and the XAML preview started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reappeared again, so I ended up creating a separate solution that linked to just the project that I intended to preview. This worked fine, and was a lot faster when it came to looking at the XAML preview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reappeared again, so I made sure that everything was building as "Any CPU".

The error disappeared, and the XAML preview started to work again.

[image]